# EXPO Google Sign In And Android app Issue

Tags: android, react-native, expo, google-signin

I am building a react native app. When I export the app to an APK file, the google sign in does not work. What happens is: I click "sign in with goolge", it will prompt me to choose an account, I select the account, spinner spins under "accounts.google.com", I am directed to google.com landing page.

In expo it will return a response and redirect me back to the app.

this is the documentation I have followed https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google/. I have checked it three times so I am sure my SSA and API keys are correct.

Has anyone else run into this issue? Is submitting Android to a apk a common issue with google sign in?

```
const signInWithGoogleAsync = async (setLoggingIn) => {
setLoggingIn(true);
try {
const result = await Google.logInAsync({
  androidClientId: GoogleClientId.Android,
  iosClientId: GoogleClientId.iOS,
  scopes: ["profile", "email"],
  iosStandaloneAppClientId: GoogleClientId.iOSStandaloneApp,
  androidStandaloneAppClientId: GoogleClientId.AndroidStandaloneApp,
});

console.log("GOOGLE LOGIN RES", result);
if (result.type === "success") {
  onSignIn(result, setLoggingIn);
  return result.accessToken;
} else {
  setLoggingIn(false);
  return {cancelled: true};
}
} catch (e) {
setLoggingIn(false);
return {error: true};
}
};
```

app.json

```
 "android": {
  "package": "123456789omittedforsecurity",
  "versionCode": 2,
  "config": {
    "googleMaps": {
      "apiKey": "123456789omittedforsecurity"
    },
    "googleSignIn": {
      "apiKey": "123456789omittedforsecurity", 
      "certificateHash": "123456789omittedforsecurity"
    }
  },
  "permissions": [
    "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
    "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
    "CAMERA",
    "MANAGE_DOCUMENTS",
    "READ_CONTACTS",
    "READ_CALENDAR",
    "WRITE_CALENDAR",
    "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
    "READ_PHONE_STATE",
    "RECORD_AUDIO",
    "USE_FINGERPRINT",
    "VIBRATE",
    "WAKE_LOCK",
    "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
    "com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT",
    "com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT",
    "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE",
    "com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION",
    "com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES",
    "com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS",
    "com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT",
    "com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE",
    "com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ",
    "com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE",
    "com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE"
  ]
},
```

As a side note: iOs is working great with expo.

Answer (score 0):

As an update, I am not entirely sure what happened but the issue stopped. I think it was my Android device that was having an issue, I upgraded the device and now it is working.